# PHP count POST elements from html form

Tags: php, arrays, post, count

I have a html form which I am sending to a php form.
I am able to set everything to a variable just fine except for one field which can have 1-20 elemnts in it.
the name of what I am trying to POST is cred_x_name
The problem is the user can put in 1 element or 20, and I am not sure how many are put in.
I know I have to use the count function, but don't know how to use it.
So far I have

```
$j=  count($cred_req_name);
for ($i=0; $i<$j;$j++)
{
echo "test";
}
```

Not sure if this is the right approach.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: `Not sure if this is the right approach.` Apparently, it isn't. What is `$cred_req_name`, and why aren't you using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having taken a look at your link, I think I would do something like the following:

```
$credentials = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
{
    if (isset($_POST['cred_'.$i.'_name']) && !empty($_POST['cred_'.$i.'_name'])
    {
        $credentials[] = array(
            'name' => $_POST['cred_'.$i.'_name'],
            'city' => $_POST['cred_'.$i.'_city'],
            //  etc
        )
    }
}
```

Then what you have is a full array of all the credentials entered by the user, and empty lines will be ignored. For instances if only 3 credentials were entered, then your array `$credentials` will be 3 elements long. You can then use this array to process what you want, such as entering credentials in a database. This time, you will use foreach to parse the array you just created.

Beware of capitalization too: `'cred_'.$i.'_name'` is not the same thing as `'Cred_'.$i.'_name'`. Turn all your "name" attributes into "cred_x_foo" (instead of "Cred_x_foo") otherwise things won't work as expected.

Anyway, don't forget to sanitize your inputs cause they don't seem to be as of now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Check out http://americanpilgrims.com/camino/credential_req.html . go down to In the fields below please enter the information for each credential I am trying to get that information to populate to a mysqk db. The only problem is i don't know if 1 cred or 20 are entered. so when i am posting the variables in my php code, I don't know how to figure out how many additional credentials were requested. thanks!

Comment: What's the problem of hunting rep points while helping obvious beginners, when oneself has only 28 rep points and his also quite a beginner? But I find your intervention funny, so I'm gonna give you some reputation by upvoting your comment...

Comment: Hi Jivan.Thanks! This is a great start. One question. When I try to do a print_r or var_dump of $credentials I only get the first name entered. The second name and city don't show up. What am I missing? thanks,ravi

Comment: Difficult to tell... Have you tried a var_dump of $_POST to make sure all the fields have been correctly posted, and that they have the correct key? If the $_POST values are correct but not correctly passed to $credentials, the problem might be in the keys. Keep me informed.

Comment: var_dump of $_POST has all the variables in it. so it is accurate. So I think the problem is in the keys.

Comment: Wait........there was no id in the html form for cred #2 i did that and it showing up now! I think I am on my way thank you SOOOOO much!!!

Comment: This is not the id, but the "name" attribute of the elements which is taken into account for the keys of $_POST. I just found your problem: look at my code edit, notice that in $_POST['cred_'.$i.'_name'] "cred" is now in lower-caps. In your form, field 1 is named "Cred_1_name" whereas all the other fields are "cred_x_blabla". Turn "Cred_1_name" into "cred_1_name" and edit your php code to lower-cap it, and everything will be perfect.